# Change text field data color (Foreground color) based on condition in JasperReports

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ireport, jdeveloper

I'm new to JasperReports. I'm designing a report using iReport. I have three values x,y,z. If z < y then the data color for z should be changed to 'black' & if z > x then data color of z should be changed to 'red'.
Please tell me how to do it.

I am using JDeveloper to develop desktop app. and iReport to design JasperReport.

Comment: Another solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40585360/how-to-set-background-color-from-parameter-in-jasper-report-designer

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use [`Conditional styles`](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/jasper/index.html#conditionalstyles) for solving this issue.

The sample:

```
<style name="ZFieldStyle">
    <conditionalStyle>
        <conditionExpression><![CDATA[$F{Z} < $F{Y}]]></conditionExpression>
        <style forecolor="#000000"/>
    </conditionalStyle>
    <conditionalStyle>
        <conditionExpression><![CDATA[$F{Z}>$F{X}]]></conditionExpression>
        <style forecolor="#FF0000"/>
    </conditionalStyle>
</style>
...
<field name="X" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
<field name="Y" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
<field name="Z" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
...
<textField>
    <reportElement style="ZFieldStyle" x="200" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
    <textElement/>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Z}]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

Comment: A few additional questions. How come I can't do the same with backcolor? Also, when I do this, the cell border color also changes... is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: You can use the backcolor property in the style