# Change BackGround color based on double value in JasperReport

Tags: jasper-reports

I am using Jasper Report 4.5.1, I have a crosstab report where I need to change the background color based on value in cell , but i am able to change the foreground color and not the background color

Below works fine

```
<style name="Crosstab Data Text">
        <conditionalStyle>
            <conditionExpression><![CDATA[$F{value}.doubleValue()==1.0d]]></conditionExpression>
            <style forecolor="#66FF66"/>
        </conditionalStyle>
        <conditionalStyle>
            <conditionExpression><![CDATA[$F{value}.doubleValue()>0.5d && $F{value}.doubleValue()=<1.0d]]></conditionExpression>
            <style forecolor="#66FF66"/>
        </conditionalStyle>
        <conditionalStyle>
            <conditionExpression><![CDATA[$F{value}.doubleValue()>0.0d && $F{value}.doubleValue()<0.5d]]></conditionExpression>
            <style forecolor="#FFFF33"/>
        </conditionalStyle>
        <conditionalStyle>
            <conditionExpression><![CDATA[$F{value}.doubleValue()>-0.5d && $F{value}.doubleValue()<0.0d]]></conditionExpression>
            <style forecolor="#FF9933"/>
        </conditionalStyle>
        <conditionalStyle>
            <conditionExpression><![CDATA[$F{value}.doubleValue()>=-1.0d && $F{value}.doubleValue()<-0.5d]]></conditionExpression>
            <style forecolor="#FF0000"/>
        </conditionalStyle>
</style>
```

But when i try the following it doesn't work

```
<style name="Crosstab Data Text" hAlign="Center">
    <conditionalStyle>
        <conditionExpression><![CDATA[$V{value}.doubleValue()>0.5d && $V{value}.doubleValue()<1.0d]]></conditionExpression>
        <style mode="Opaque" backcolor="#00FF00" fill="Solid"/>
    </conditionalStyle>
    <conditionalStyle>
        <conditionExpression><![CDATA[$V{value}.doubleValue()>0.0d && $V{value}.doubleValue()<0.5d]]></conditionExpression>
        <style mode="Opaque" backcolor="#0000FF" fill="Solid"/>
    </conditionalStyle>
    <conditionalStyle>
        <conditionExpression><![CDATA[$V{value}.doubleValue()>-0.5d && $V{value}.doubleValue()<0.0d]]></conditionExpression>
        <style mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FF00FF" fill="Solid"/>
    </conditionalStyle>
    <conditionalStyle>
        <conditionExpression><![CDATA[$V{value}.doubleValue()>=-1.0d && $V{value}.doubleValue()<-0.5d]]></conditionExpression>
        <style mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FF0000" fill="Solid"/>
    </conditionalStyle>
</style>
```

I tried using 'backcolor="#FF0000" fill="Solid"' or 'mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FF0000"' still it didnt work ... not sure if this functionality is not supported ... or am i doing something wrong ??

similar question was asked here
[Change text field data color (Foreground color) based on condition in JasperReports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8754448/change-text-field-data-color-foreground-color-based-on-condition-in-jasperrepo)

```
<crosstabCell width="58" height="26">
                    <cellContents>
                        <textField pattern="#0.##" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                            <reportElement style="Crosstab Data Text" mode="Transparent" x="0" y="0" width="58" height="26"/>
                            <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                <font fontName="Calibri" size="9"/>
                            </textElement>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{value}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabCell>
                <crosstabCell height="25" rowTotalGroup="text1">
                    <cellContents backcolor="#FFBFBF" mode="Opaque">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement style="Crosstab Data Text" x="0" y="0" width="50" height="25"/>
                            <textElement/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{value}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabCell>
                <crosstabCell width="50" columnTotalGroup="text2">
                    <cellContents backcolor="#FFBFBF" mode="Opaque">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement style="Crosstab Data Text" x="0" y="0" width="50" height="25"/>
                            <textElement/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{value}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabCell>
                <crosstabCell rowTotalGroup="text1" columnTotalGroup="text2">
                    <cellContents backcolor="#FFBFBF" mode="Opaque">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement style="Crosstab Data Text" x="0" y="0" width="50" height="25"/>
                            <textElement/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{value}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabCell>
            </crosstab>
```

Answer (score 2):

found the issue changed

```
 <reportElement style="Crosstab Data Text" mode="Transparent" x="0" y="0" width="58" height="26"/>
```

to

```
 <reportElement style="Crosstab Data Text"  x="0" y="0" width="58" height="26"/>
```

And it worked fine

Comment: had the same problem,+1 for the nice answer

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is with the order of conditions , all the conditions in the style should be in the order like in my style I am first checking whether the revenue > 100 then > 75 , >25 and >0 ,in this case if first condition is true then it will not go to next condition and if first condition is not true then it will go to second condition and  so on.

Just check the condition order in your style.

`<style name="s_total_revenue">
        <conditionalStyle>
            <conditionExpression><![CDATA[($F{ACT_REVENUE}/$F{TARGET_REVENUE})*100 >100]]></conditionExpression>
            <style mode="Opaque" forecolor="#FFFFFF" backcolor="#006633" fill="Solid"/>
        </conditionalStyle>
        <conditionalStyle>
            <conditionExpression><![CDATA[($F{ACT_REVENUE}/$F{TARGET_REVENUE})*100 > 75]]></conditionExpression>
            <style mode="Transparent" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#00FF33" fill="Solid"/>
        </conditionalStyle>
        <conditionalStyle>
            <conditionExpression><![CDATA[($F{ACT_REVENUE}/$F{TARGET_REVENUE})*100 > 25]]></conditionExpression>
            <style mode="Opaque" forecolor="#FFFFFF" backcolor="#FFFF00" fill="Solid"/>
        </conditionalStyle>
        <conditionalStyle>
            <conditionExpression><![CDATA[($F{ACT_REVENUE}/$F{TARGET_REVENUE})*100 >0]]></conditionExpression>
            <style mode="Opaque" forecolor="#FFFFFF" backcolor="#990000" fill="Solid"/>
        </conditionalStyle>
    </style>`