# Jasper report : set 1 conditional style to multiple textfields

Tags: jasper-reports

I have 50 different textfields on my report.
I need to set a background color (blue, red or yellow) on each of these textfields based on their value.

Do I need to set 50 conditional styles?
Or can I create one conditional style and apply it on each of the 50 textfields(with the value of the textfield as a parameter of the style)?

Thank you.

Comment: Hope this helps....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8754448/change-text-field-data-color-foreground-color-based-on-condition-in-jasperrepo