# JasperStudio How to use conditional style?

Tags: jasper-reports, format, conditional-statements

I am desperately trying to format the Field "FilmID" based on it's value. Could you provide me with a conditional expression to format values >= 3 in red color ?

[Conditional Style](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ui4om.jpg)

Thanks a lot in advance!

Another variant of this question would be, what did I do wrong in this expression:

```
<style name="Style1" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#DBD82A">
        <conditionalStyle>
            <conditionExpression><![CDATA[$F{Revenue} > 10000]]></conditionExpression>
            <style mode="Opaque" backcolor="#C92B28"/>
        </conditionalStyle>
    </style>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change text field data color (Foreground color) based on condition in JasperReports](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8754448/change-text-field-data-color-foreground-color-based-on-condition-in-jasperrepo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `$F{Revenue}` is numeric (`Integer`, `Double`, `Float` ecc)

if you are using jasper report version `6.0` or above there is nothing wrong with your style expression, for jasper report `3.0`, you need `new Boolean($F{Revenue} > 10000)`in expression.

You need also to be sure that you apply the style to a report element.

```
<reportElement style="style1" x="49" y="4" width="100" height="20" uuid="865e11e4-c2d4-40ac-be06-dc1359dc93c0"/>
```

Comment: It is strange, later that day I tried the exact same thing as before and it worked both for string and numerical values.

Comment: That it worked with $F{Revenue} as String is really strange!, jasper report should exit with error "The operator < is undefined for the argument type(s) String, int"

Comment: Maybe it matters if report language is set to groovy or Java ? Also only != works with string, while == doesn't. However equals does.

Comment: If you use groovy == is compareTo (should work), it will compile and it will compare your String to your int..., , however < or > will not  work in groovy.