# How to display a message if numeric value falls between two numbers?

Tags: jasper-reports

JasperReport question: I have table with user data and % value of completed test. How to display the String message of value if it is in certain Number range.

```
Values between 0 and 59 = `Try again`
Values more than 59 = `Doing great`
```

I used for

```
Parameter1 $P{Value 1}
Class: java.lang.Long
Expression: $F{percentage}<59.00
Parameter1 $P{Value 2}
Class: java.lang.Long
Expression: $F{percentage}>59.01
```

Created Detail [Text Field] with following Expression:

```
IF($P{Value 1},`Try again`,`Doing great`)
```

Report State:

> Value 1 cannot be resolved to a variable.

Comment: between two number?, you have not specified what happens if lower then 0... I posted an answer, you can nested as many ternary expression as you need.

Comment: Other try (Working solution) : IF($F{percentage}<59,"Try again","Doing great")

Comment: don't use IF, use ternary operator as I have answered.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need variables for this instead just use a [ternary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:) in you textField expression

```
$F{percentage}<=59?"Try again":"Doing great".
```

Your example is not really "between" it's instead just one condition but if you also need "between" you can just nest another ternary operator as in example below (percentage<0)

```
<textField>
    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="545" height="20" uuid="43ce93f2-5984-4127-a394-89348e83185b"/>
    <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{percentage}<0?"Opps":$F{percentage}<=59?"Try again":"Doing great"]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

If you also like to **style** the textField accordingly you can use conditional style see for example [JasperStudio How to use conditional style?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33588981/jasperstudio-how-to-use-conditional-style)