# How to change backcolor of label based on textfield in jasper Reporting

Tags: jasper-reports

I have texfield  and a label i want to change the background color of label based on  the value of texfield  ,if  the value of texfield is not null then the backcolor of label must change .

```
 <style name="Color1">
    <conditionalStyle>
        <conditionExpression><![CDATA[$F{check1}=="0.00"]]></conditionExpression>
        <style mode="Opaque" backcolor="#4F110F"/>
    </conditionalStyle>
</style>

<textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement x="140" y="50" width="34" height="24" backcolor="#4F110F" uuid="a792c8a7-ad7e-4f28-b8c0-cc0fce54030a"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[($F{check1} != null) ? $F{check1} : "0.00"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
```

above is my texfield conditional expression  for textfield
and below is the label

```
<staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" mode="Opaque" x="180" y="57" width="40" height="18" forecolor="#120808" backcolor="#FAFAFA" uuid="1f31c82f-cfca-4930-bee9-890c0dacca8d">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <box topPadding="0" leftPadding="0">
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="11" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Yes]]></text>
            </staticText>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change text field data color (Foreground color) based on condition in JasperReports](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8754448/change-text-field-data-color-foreground-color-based-on-condition-in-jasperrepo)

Answer (score 0):

Try applying the "Color1" style to your StaticText element something like this:

```
<staticText>
    <reportElement style="Color1" positionType="Float" ... >
        ...
    </reportElement>
    ...
</staticText>
```

Answer (score 0):

First Remove Forecolor,backcolor, mode from your label. and add your style to it.

```
<staticText>
  <reportElement style="Color1" positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" x="180" y="57" width="40" height="18" uuid="1f31c82f-cfca-4930-bee9-890c0dacca8d">
  <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
  <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
  </reportElement>
  <box topPadding="0" leftPadding="0">
  <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
  <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
  <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
  <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
  </box>
  <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
        <font fontName="SansSerif" size="11" isBold="true"/>
  </textElement>
  <text><![CDATA[Yes]]></text>
</staticText>
```

If your condition, $F{check1} == "0.00" is not working. then try .equals property of java. $F{check1}.equals("0.00") or convert it into same datatype 
like new BigDecimal($F{check1}) == new BigDecimal("0.00")