# How to set background color from parameter in Jasper Report designer

Tags: jasper-reports

I am using Jasper Report for designing report. I have a report where there is a static text. I want to set the background color of it by parameter value. In the XML it generates for the text like this:

`<reportElement mode="Opaque" x="434" y="0" width="121" height="12" backcolor="#A6A6A6" uuid="e088bd9f-a0ac-4f34-9375-df765c829ec2"/>`.

Now I need to set the backcolor from a parameter which will come from database. for here like `#A6A6A6`.

What can I try next? I have researched it, but no luck.

Comment: You should use Conditional styles

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change text field data color (Foreground color) based on condition in JasperReports](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8754448/change-text-field-data-color-foreground-color-based-on-condition-in-jasperrepo)

Comment: @AlexK I can use conditional style. But there I can not use color code from db table. I have to put color code manually for each condition which I don't want. The user will set the color code in table and I will use that through parameter

Comment: `backcolor="#A6A6A6"` - How to use parameter instead of `#A6A6A6` here? Can you please help

Comment: You can't use expression like this: `backcolor="$P{someColor}"`. You can try to use *JasperReports API* or wrappers over it

Comment: @AlexK can you please provide some code example for  JasperReports API or wrappers

Comment: [ConditionalStyleReport](http://www.dynamicreports.org/examples/conditionalstylereport) from *DynamicReports API*

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do that with [net.sf.jasperreports.style.*](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/config.reference.html#net.sf.jasperreports.style.%7Bstyle_property_suffix%7D) element level properties (for which you can have expressions as values).

In your case you would need

```
<textField>
  <reportElement ...>
    <propertyExpression name="net.sf.jasperreports.style.backcolor">$P{someColor}</propertyExpression>
  </reportElement>
  ...
```

Comment: thanks a lot. this is really a nice requirement and nice solution

Comment: If you don't want to edit the xml yourself, you can find this in the properties tab of an element (eg a `Rectangle`). Properties->advanced->misc->Edit Properties->design->net.sf.jasperreports.style.backcolor. You can add expressions there.

Comment: @dada67 is it possible to use <propertyExpression> into <conditionalStyle> ?

Comment: No, style properties can only be applied directly to report elements.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

click the "transparent"